# Telegram bot: Show full text as ReplyKeyboardMarkup button

Tags: php, button, telegram-bot

I'm working on a Poll-like Bot where I want to show the choices as buttons.
Some choices consist of 10 or more words.
When I but that text in as a button, the middle words converted to dots.
i.e:
"We have the capacity to receive messages from the stars and the songs of the night winds."

When I put this as a button, it will show like this:
"We have the capacity to ... of the night winds".

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest you; using of command instead of reply keyboard.
you can easily add slash and number to beginning of your choices, so user can click on it:

```
/1 We have the capacity to receive messages from the stars and the songs of the night winds.
/2 We have not the capacity to receive messages from the stars and the songs of the night winds.
/3 test test test
/4 example example example
```

the `/1`, `/2`, `/3` and `/4` will convert to link and convert to clickable text.

Comment: Yep, that was my choice too.